# How can I use relational algebra to determine when changes to a relation invalidate the results of an expression?

Tags: relation-algebra

My goal is to take a series of modifications to relations in an SQL database, and check if I need to re-run other SQL queries because their results would change. Allowing people to listen to changes to an SQL query.

I found a similar problem is "how to incrementally refresh a materialized view".

[Here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Incremental_View_Maintenance#Basic_Theory_of_IVM) is an unimplemented proposal for Postgres that uses relational algebra to optimize this process.

I am looking for something slightly different though. The above proposal calculates the delta for these queries, but I want to know whether I need to calculate the delta in the first place based on the actual query selections.

For a series of changes (update, insert, delete), taking into account the values of the tuple, how can I work out if the query results need to be updated at all.

In practice it would be:

```
function doesQueryNeedRefresh([changes], query): Boolean { return ... }
```

For example, if we look at different mutations to the `list` relation, here are the conditions that invalidate the query.

```
select name from list where list_id = 1
```

- update:

  - if old `list_id = 1` and `list_id` changes
  - `name` attr changes
- insert:

  - if `list_id = 1`
- delete:

  - if `list_id = 1`

But then it gets more complex with joins:

```
select l.name, i.name from list as l
inner join list_items as li on li.list_id = l.id
inner join items as i on i.id = li.item_id
where items.completed = true
```

For this query, if we look at a single mutation to each relation in isolation:

- `list`

  - create: if `list_items.list_id` contains `list.id`
  - update: if `name` changes or `list.id`
  - delete: if `list_items.list_id` contains `list.id`
- `list_items`

  - create: if `list_id` is in `list`, or `item_id` is in `items`
  - update: if foreign keys change (because of no projection)
  - delete: if `list_id` is in `list`, or `item_id` is in `items`
- `items`

  - create: if `completed = true` and `id` in `list_items.item_id`
  - update: if `id` in `list_items.item_id`
  - delete: if `id` in `list_items.item_id`

We could do less checks by assuming that some values cannot change such as primary and foreign keys.

Also, instead of deleting rows, what if we marked things as `deleted = true`, maybe this would make it simpler.

Is there a way to formalize this in relational algebra? And also, does this help me efficiently perform these calculations?

---

I am also interested in the smallest subset of these relations that are necessary for these checks to run. Use case: I maintain a local database that syncs a portion of the data from the cloud database, and I want to run queries locally,